# How do I play this chord?

Tags: piano, chords, technique, physical-limitations

How would one play this chord? I am 6'2" and have medium to large hands but there is no way I can reach from the E to G#. Is there a trick to it?

[image: A chord from Gershwin's "Rhapsody in Blue" piano solo score]

Comment: Note that the chord in indicated as rolled and pedal is common in this piece.

Comment: That squiggly line just before the dots is the answer: it means *arpeggiate*, or play each note in succession, quickly, using pedal to hold the already played notes on. There is no pedal marking but it's assumed that the sustain pedal is used.

Answer (score 1):

These are usually handled by rolling the chord and using some pedal. There other techniques: